# How to get the ID for 1 record from MYSQL database, then pass it to the details page for viewing using dynamic php & mysqli

Tags: php, database, mysqli, records

I have a html page listing all the jobs in my database, I managed to get everything displaying on [www.mysite/alljobs.php](http://www.mysite/alljobs.php) (or the list all records page), great, but I cannot get hold of the different id's from this page to display on a dynamic link to showing the job details for each job i.e [www.mysite/thejob.php?job_id=8](http://www.mysite/thejob.php?job_id=8) (the specific record details page).

I have recently had to upgrade my PHP version to PHP7 and need to use MYSQLI  with PHP. Can any help with the code I need for both the list page and the details page so that dynamic pages are created when I click on the alljobs.php links.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which part is a problem for you? Creating the link including the parameter `thejob.php?job_id=<job_id>`  or reading the parameter passed in the url ?

Comment: the first issue is creating the link as you say. I am trying to use ** <? echo '<a href="vacancy.php?job_id='.$id.'">'.'{{data.job_ref}}-{{data.job_id}}'.'</a>';?> ** I can see the various links but am stumped how to get the $id to contain the job_id for each link.  I am connected to the database as all the jobs are appearing but I can only see ** vacancy.php?job_id= ** when I hover over the link, no numbers are being generated. So on clicking the detail pages says 'there is no data to render this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over your query results and print out the ID for each one in a link, like this

```
<?php
  foreach ($myQueryResults as $item){
?>

<a href="www.mysite/thejob.php?job_id=<?php echo $item->id;?>"> Link </a>

<?php
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `<a>` per record, you could put the id in the href, something like this:

```
<a href="www.mysite/thejob.php?job_id=<?php echo $id;?>"> Link </a>
```

Comment: no i am using - <? echo '<a href="vacancy.php?job_id='.$id.'">'.'{{data.job_ref}}-{{data‌​.job_id}}'.'</a>';?> in a table

Comment: <tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
<td>
<? echo '<a href="vacancy.php?job_id='.$id.'">'.'{{data.job_ref}}-{{data.job_id}}'.'</a>';?></td><td>{{data.type_job}}</td><td>{{data.location}}</td><td>{{data.title}}</td><td>{{data.experience_req}} Years</td><td>{{data.start_date}}</td>               <td>{{data.language_req}}</td></tr></tbody> - The problem is trying to get the $id to be the job_id from my database. I have tried various ways to 'SELECT * FROM Vacancies'.

Comment: try my answer, it should work. I do that all the time

Answer (score 1):

you can pass your id variable in php quote with echo

```
<a href="www.mysite/thejob.php?job_id=<?php echo $id;?>">View</a>
```

Comment: Ok. But what is the MYSQLI way of getting the $ID from the database? It did work until I upgraded then various mysql code came up as depreciated...

Answer (score 1):

you can send the id on link url and the get with `$jobID = <?php $_GET['id']?>`on that page. Don't forget to sanitize.

`<a href="www.mysite/thejob.php?id=<?php echo $jobId;?>">Details</a>`